# How to get the values(real time) of PyMongo document which has an embedded array of key value pairs

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

```
student_info=Studentdb.db.Student.find_one({'username': current_user.username})
```

The complete document would get returned by this as above

Trying to get the marks for each of the tests summed up by using:

```
subject_info = student_info['subjects.subject_name)']
```

Getting key error

> KeyError: subjects.subject_name

Intended usage is:

Need to get the values(which are numbers) of keys dynamically for Unit_Test1, Unit_Test2, Unit_Test3,MidTerm, Annual and sum them for all subjects

If there is no list like subjects, it is easy to get using subject_info['user_name'] and subject_info['status']

`find()` function needs a value however would like to get the value dynamically from the mongodb Pymongo document. Any leads would help as relatively new to this.

Tried to get the marks for each of the tests summed up by using:

```
subject_info = student_info['subjects.subject_name)']
```

Getting key error

> KeyError: subjects.subject_name

```
{
    "_id" : Grade01
    "user_name" : "TestUser",
    "status" : "active",
    "subjects" : [
            {
                    "subject_name" : "Computer",
                    "Unit_Test1 " : 95,
                    "Unit_Test2" : 96,
                    "Unit_Test3" : 94,
                    "MidTerml" : 99,
                    "Annual" : 96
            },
            {

                   "subject_name" : "Science", 
      "Unit_Test1 " : 92,
                    "Unit_Test2" : 92,
                    "Unit_Test3" : 93,
                    "MidTerm" : 95,
                    "Annual" : 97
            },
    {

                   "subject_name" : "Maths", 
      "Unit_Test1 " : 96,
                    "Unit_Test2" : 94,
                    "Unit_Test3" : 93,
                    "MidTerm" : 95,
                    "Annual" : 99
            },

}

student_info=Studentdb.db.Student.find_one({'username': current_user.username})
```

Expecting results like this:

For specific user (matching the username), matching the subjects like subjects.subject_name and once the student and subject name is matched the corresponding marks for the same can be used and computing the total marks for each individual tests Unit_Test1, Unit_Test2, Unit_Test3, MidTerm, Annual for all the subjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. your request returns a dictionary, which is excellent:

```
>>> student_info = {'_id': 'Grade01', 'user_name': 'TestUser', 'status': 'active', 'subjects': [{'subject_name': 'Computer', 'Unit_Test1 ': 95, 'Unit_Test2': 96, 'Unit_Test3': 94, 'MidTerml': 99, 'Annual': 96}, {'subject_name': 'Science', 'Unit_Test1 ': 92, 'Unit_Test2': 92, 'Unit_Test3': 93, 'MidTerm': 95, 'Annual': 97}, {'subject_name': 'Maths', 'Unit_Test1 ': 96, 'Unit_Test2': 94, 'Unit_Test3': 93, 'MidTerm': 95, 'Annual': 99}]}
>>> student_info['subjects']
[{'subject_name': 'Computer', 'Unit_Test1 ': 95, 'Unit_Test2': 96, 'Unit_Test3': 94, 'MidTerml': 99, 'Annual': 96}, {'subject_name': 'Science', 'Unit_Test1 ': 92, 'Unit_Test2': 92, 'Unit_Test3': 93, 'MidTerm': 95, 'Annual': 97}, {'subject_name': 'Maths', 'Unit_Test1 ': 96, 'Unit_Test2': 94, 'Unit_Test3': 93, 'MidTerm': 95, 'Annual': 99}]
>>> student_info['subjects'][0]
{'subject_name': 'Computer', 'Unit_Test1 ': 95, 'Unit_Test2': 96, 'Unit_Test3': 94, 'MidTerml': 99, 'Annual': 96}
>>> student_info['subjects'][0]['subject_name']
'Computer'
```

This little command-line exercise shows how you can reach every piece of information in the dictionary.

**Now the code to manage all this dynamically**

```
student_info = {'_id': 'Grade01', 'user_name': 'TestUser', 'status': 'active', 'subjects': [{'subject_name': 'Computer', 'Unit_Test1 ': 95, 'Unit_Test2': 96, 'Unit_Test3': 94, 'MidTerml': 99, 'Annual': 96}, {'subject_name': 'Science', 'Unit_Test1 ': 92, 'Unit_Test2': 92, 'Unit_Test3': 93, 'MidTerm': 95, 'Annual': 97}, {'subject_name': 'Maths', 'Unit_Test1 ': 96, 'Unit_Test2': 94, 'Unit_Test3': 93, 'MidTerm': 95, 'Annual': 99}]}
subjects = student_info['subjects']
result = {}
for i in subjects:
    total = 0
    one_subject = ''
    for key, value in i.items():
        if key == 'subject_name':
            one_subject = value
        else:
            total += int(value)
    result[one_subject] = total
print(result)
```

This code generates a dictionary with as keys the different subjects and as values ​​the total of each individual test. The result gives:

```
{'Computer': 480, 'Science': 469, 'Maths': 477}
```